# Get the name of provisioning profile in xcode

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I have some expired(unused) provisioning profile in my xcode. I want to delete them but the problem is in my `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/` folder the provisioning profiles are not saved with the name but a hexadecimal string like

```
03264601-561e-4185-b6b9-968b168d57a1.mobileprovision
31266708-96d8-4496-88ce-8c2a1681d5c6.mobileprovision
3d26aa08-16ef-4023-a563-ec77168a6043.mobileprovision
4926b573-36f4-4235-9519-5534168b3f9c.mobileprovision
4926eb37-a630-4ca4-989c-0e66168c3795.mobileprovision
6d26b1f0-0695-4bfc-9ae0-a2051680acac.mobileprovision
7c26c1da-a65f-4277-ac1d-c81116828035.mobileprovision
8626b58b-06f3-4aaf-8d1e-f9e61683572d.mobileprovision
af26b527-06d7-476a-888f-2d3a16829277.mobileprovision
f02695b0-6623-47ed-b766-cbb1168ab752.mobileprovision
```

How can I get the name of each provisioning so that I can delete them. I don't want to delete all and then reinstall the rest.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Easy Way

Go to the folder `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/` and select a profile and hit space bar you'll see something like this

[image]

## Geeky Way

I have created the script [GitHub/ListProvisioningProfileName](https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/ListProvisioningProfileName). You can find the steps of usage there.

When you run the script it will show the output like below

`$ list-provisioning-profile-name.sh`

#### Example Output

```
03174601-551e-4185-b6b9-968b7ebd57a1.mobileprovision    ad hoc myprofile
31456708-99d8-4496-88ce-8c2acee1d5c6.mobileprovision    xc ad hoc: com.abc.ios.*
3d45aa08-1cef-4023-a563-ec77f99a6043.mobileprovision    cool water
4912b573-3df4-4235-9519-5534fc5b3f9c.mobileprovision    Fast and Furious
4912eb37-a030-4ca4-989c-0e66cb7c3795.mobileprovision    adhoc-nursery-poems
6d21b1f0-0595-4bfc-9ae0-a2053ad0acac.mobileprovision    me team dist
7c21c1da-a65f-4277-ac1d-c81161728035.mobileprovision    myapp
8621b58b-04f3-4aaf-8d1e-f9e67183572d.mobileprovision    HelloExample
af21b527-05d7-476a-888f-2d3a3d429277.mobileprovision    xc ad hoc: com.abc.ios.name
f01125b0-6623-47ed-b766-cbb1138ab752.mobileprovision    my-dev-wild`
```

Comment: Great script, with Xcode 8.3 or newer it's almost a must-have. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete them all, then open *Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > YourAccount > View Details* and press the refresh button in the lower left corner. That will reload the latest versions from the Developer Portal.

You can as well navigate here, then right click on any Profile to open the folder where they are stored.