# Find a specific provisioning profile in Xcode 8.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode

Up until recently, the provisioning profiles were found under `Settings - Accounts - [Account] - [Team name]`. However, since the 8.3.1 release of Xcode, they are no longer shown. Instead, the certificates are there.

This is quite annoying, since I want to delete one specific profile. I know the files are stored in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`, but right there, their ID's are shown rather than their names, so I don't know which ones I'm looking at.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: Add iphone configuration utility. You will find all Provisioning Profiles there.

Comment: This answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864447/get-the-name-of-provisioning-profile?answertab=active#tab-top